# vba 'Compiler error expected: =' on saveAs operation

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, save-as

The following line in my VBA code is generating the compile error 'Compiler error expected: =' implying that it expected an assignment. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

I just want to save the file. Also, I want to overwrite the file which was previously a .xls or .xlsx file. Will this line do that?

```
Workbooks(theFile).SaveAs("Z:\test\vhb\" & newName, xlCSV)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You do not use parentheses unless you are assigning to a variable.

```
Workbooks(theFile).SaveAs "Z:\test\vhb\" & newName, xlCSV
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't make sense to me to assign my saving.

Comment: @Brian if you really want to use the parentheses you can use `Call`: `Call Workbooks(theFile).SaveAs("Z:\test\vhb\" & newName, xlCSV)` -- but I have to say I really don't like this approach, because it adds nothing other than verbosity.